# Extend Lines To Another Feature (Polyline)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line

I am trying to convert the polyline shapefile shown in the picture below to polygon in order to fill in the "narrower" area between them as I am trying to get the right-of-way shapefile.

[image: Lines]
However, two problems arise:

1. The Feature to Polygon will automatically fill the bigger space between the lines.
2. The lines aren't exactly connected. The gaps are shown below

[image: Gaps]

These lines are divided by different tiles. Each polyline shapefile is in a grid shown as below.

[image: LinesInGrid]

What I want to do is to first extend the lines to the grid boundary as there is also gap between them. If that works, then run a iterator to all the polyline features. Then merge them all.

Is there a way for me to extend the lines to the grid boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Advanced license and ArcMap 10.3 or later you can use the [Generate Edgematch Links](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/generate-edgematch-links.htm) and [Edgematch Features tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/edgematch-features.htm) to help solve this type of problem.  Look at the help links and let us know if you have any problems using these tools.  Without an Advanced license your options will be very limited and require extensive programming knowledge to do what Esri tools can do.  You will have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Works like a wonder. Another thing is, I don't just have these two grids. More like 50 of them. How shall I accomplish all that via iterator model? I was using Generate Edgematch Links, how shall I distinguish between source features and adjacent features? Thanks again

Comment: I would not do this in model Builder.  I would do it with a Python script.  Too much logic needed to keep track of rows and columns without regard to order.  Also Python can do more sophisticated output name patterns.  But since I have no idea how you have named your files to indicate rows or columns (if you have at all), you're on your own until you give more details in a new post about what you have to work with that would let a program identify adjacency of the feature classes.

Comment: They are all kept in grids and indexed. So I think the naming wouldn't be too big a problem. Do you think it's achievable? Thanks